# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'avatar' was called on null

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, nosuchmethoderror

Have looked at similar questions, can't see any common mistakes. Once the factory seems to create the object with no issues. However, calling any of the methods generates a NoSuchMethodError. Been debugging for days, out of ideas. Have similar code using data models of that general layout with no issues.

This is the code for the data model

```
class Performer {
  String avatar, header, name, username;
  int id, subscribePrice;
  bool isRealPerformer,
      isPerformer,
      hasStories,
      hasStream,
      isPaywallRestriction;

  Performer(
      {this.avatar,
      this.header,
      this.name,
      this.username,
      this.id,
      this.subscribePrice,
      this.isRealPerformer,
      this.isPerformer,
      this.hasStories,
      this.hasStream,
      this.isPaywallRestriction});

  factory Performer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> performer) {
    return Performer(
        avatar: performer["avatar"],
        header: performer["header"],
        name: performer["name"],
        username: performer["username"],
        id: performer["id"],
        subscribePrice: performer["subscribePrice"],
        isRealPerformer: performer["isRealPerformer"],
        isPerformer: performer["isPerformer"],
        hasStories: performer["hasStories"],
        hasStream: performer["hasStream"],
        isPaywallRestriction: performer["isPaywallRestriction"]);
  }
}
```

This is the code that populates the models

```
Future<List<Performer>> getSubscriptions() async {
    List<Performer> performers = [];

    String url = "some API url";

    String res = await _callServer(url);

    if (res.isNotEmpty) {
      List<dynamic> payload = json.decode(res);

      payload.forEach((element) {
        performers.add(new Performer.fromJson(element));
      });
      return performers;

    } else return performers;
  }

Future<Performer> getPerformer(int performerID) async {
    List<Performer> subs = await getSubscriptions();

    Performer performer;

    int prefIndex;

    for (int x = 0; x < subs.length; x++) {
      if (subs[x].id == performerID){
        performer = subs[x];
        break;
      }
    }

    if (performer.avatar != null) {
      print("found ${performer.username}");
      return performer;
    } else return null;
  }
```

This is the code that generates the UI element based on the model

```
class ProfilePic extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  ProfilePic({Key key, @required this.id}) : super();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _profilePicState();
}

class _profilePicState extends State<ProfilePic> {
  Performer performer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    Backend().getPerformer(widget.id).then((value) {
      performer = value;
      setState(() {});
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("profile for: ${widget.id}");
    return Container(
      child: performer == null ? Container() : CircleAvatar(
        radius: 30.0,
        backgroundImage:
        NetworkImage(performer.avatar),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Check the API response, maybe there is a spelling mistake for the filed "avatar" because it seems like the avatar in the model is storing null. I think that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: It is not the avatar field that is null @theCaptainXgod, It is the object.

Comment: @Locked created a button that calls that function and all methods work funny enough.

Comment: But this error persists?

Comment: @theCaptainXgod created a test button that works just fine, but not the UI image code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code was returning the post ID not the User ID to the function, hence the null error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getSubscriptions`, try

```
payload.forEach((element) {
        performers.add(new Performer.fromJson(Map.from(element)));
});
```

Comment: Okay. Can you print `res` before the foreach loop?

Comment: calling that function in a button prints the avatar for some reason

Comment: Where were you calling the function before @Edmund?

Comment: figured it out, was passing the post ID instead of the userID hence the null error